# What is the purpose of this Javascript function regexp_quote?

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript I found and have to use but I don't understand what it is doing. Specifically, the regexp_quote() function. Can anyone help me understand what it would be trying to do here? It appears to be doing nothing but there might be some scenario where it actually does something.

```
function replace(input, pattern, flags, str){

    return input.replace(new RegExp(regexp_quote(pattern), flags), str);
}
function regexp_quote(str) {
     return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
 }

var dateTime = "2016-03-09T13:18:21-05:00"
dateTime.replace(new RegExp(regexp_quote(':'), 'g'), '.')
```

Comment: It adds escape markers to common RegExp characters. Perhaps you should read this article on [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Just try `regexp_quote('.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-')`, and it's _very_ obvious what it is doing.

Comment: Aha! I see it now! Thank you .... that sneaky \\$1 got me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @BrianTHannan Sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/` is a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with a single *capture group*, encompassing a *character set*, which in turn contains common characters that have special meaning in Regular Expressions.

The function `regexp_quote` takes a String, and globally replaces each instance of a character found in the set, with an *escaped* version (one with a preceding backslash). `$1` indicates use of the first (and only) capture group.

`regexp_quote('.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-')` returns `'\.\?\*\+\^\$\[\]\\\(\)\{\}\|\-'`, showing the very obvious escape prefixing of characters.

Comment: "Common characters", or "all characters"?

Comment: @torazaburo Common. There are other characters that have special meaning in Regular Expressions, when escaped (`d`, `w`, `s`, etc.).

Comment: Well, those aren't really "special characters" and don't need to be handled separately, since escaping the backslash will take care of them.

Comment: You're muddling words by trying to be pedantic like this. I did not say that `d`, `w`, `s` are special characters in regular expressions, but their escaped versions have _special meaning_. The current set of characters _lose_ special meaning when escaped. If you added `bdstw` to the start of that character set, you would be in effect _inversely adding_ functionality to a `RegExp` constructed from the resulting string, but there's no need to get so bloody precise in an answer of this magnitude - one that barely scratches the surface of regular expressions.